# Connection must be open C#

Tags: c#, mysql

So heres my code

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=rfid;Uid=root;password=;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "Select * from users WHERE id_no = " + this.id_no.Text;
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    label1.Text = "ID Number: " + reader["id_no"].ToString();
    label2.Text = "Name: " + reader["name"].ToString();
    label3.Text = "User type: " + reader["user_type"].ToString();
    id_no.Text = "";
}
```

It says Connection must be valid and open.
I already checked my Firewall and set it off. apache and mysql port running. what is the possible error in my code?

Comment: you are missing `conn.Open`

Comment: And would close after do your query.

Comment: @AndrewPaes better yet: enclose it in a `using` block

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski for sure a way better.

Comment: I would look into command parameters, and wrapping this in a try catch as well since you will be firing this every time someone changes the text based upon code below.  Definitely a using statement as well to make sure you are cleaning up resources each time you call this.

Answer (score 2):

You should put all IDisposable classes in a using statement, this includes your connection object.  Do it like this, which includes the disposal and opening of the connection:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    //Do Work
}
```

Comment: I should also mention that your command and reader objects are also IDisposable, and are candidates for a using statement.  Read about IDisposable and the using statement, it really comes in handy.